# Not able to run the query since mysql is considering the string as column name

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert data into my sql table using data stored in the list
The code I am using is:

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO final_attendance (Fac_id,Subject,Name,roll_id) VALUES ({fac}, {sub}, {name}, {roll})".format(
                       fac = row['Fac_id'],
                       sub = row['Subject'],
                       name = row['Name'],
                       roll = row['roll_id']))
```

But when I run this code sql considers the data stored in the list as a column name rather than normal Varchar

for Example:
The correct sql syntax to input data is

```
INSERT INTO final_attendance (Fac_id, Subject, Name, roll_id) 
VALUES ("PRD", "CSE", "Tanmay Pardhi", 59)
```

But what my code writes is

```
INSERT INTO final_attendance (Fac_id, Subject, Name, roll_id) 
VALUES (PRD, CSE, Tanmay Pardhi, 59)
```

And so it considers PRD as a column name
Error on execution is "Unknown column 'PRD' in 'field list"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: String literals must be enclosed with quotes. Try `.. VALUES ('{fac}', '{sub}', '{name}', {roll})` (roll is not quoted because of numeric value)

Comment: Try protecting columns with double quotes and strings with single quotes. If you need to escape quotes within a python string use ```\```.

Comment: Thank you @Akina so much. I spent hours trying to concatenate those apostrophe marks. Grateful for you help.

Comment: Yes, will keep that in mind @AlexanderEble. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the %s placeholder see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO final_attendance (Fac_id,Subject,Name,roll_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",(
                    row['Fac_id'],
                    row['Subject'],
                    row['Name'],
                    row['roll_id']))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use %s it takes care of strings:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO final_attendance (Fac_id,Subject,Name,roll_id) VALUES (%s, %s,%s,%s)",row['Fac_id'],row['Subject'],row['Name'],row['roll_id']))
```

Comment: Thanks the placeholders and apostrophe are working. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of VALUES `({fac}, {sub}, {name}, {roll})` need to use `values (%s, %s, %s, %d)` .

Comment: Thanks it's working and the placeholders also prove to be easier to use than string formatting.

Comment: Yup. You are most welcome @TanmayPardhi. Best wishes.